# Why is outlook.com moving text underline?

Tags: html-email

In my html email, I have two white links underlined and this works everywhere except Outlook.com/Office 365. On those sites the links aren't underlined but some other unrelated non-linked text is?!

The underline from the link here:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="15" bgcolor="#001342">
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" align="center" valign="middle" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 24px; color: #ffffff;">
            <p>Register onto <span style="color: #ffb718;">X</span> by completing the short form <a href="#" style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: underline!important;">here</a></p>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

Appears to be getting applied here instead:

<tr>
    <td width="50" align="left" valign="middle">
        <img src="images/icon-clipboard.gif" alt="" width="40" height="40" border="0">
    </td>
    <td class="list-text" align="left" valign="middle" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 26px; line-height: 30px; color: #001342;">
        <p style="text-decoration: none!important;"><span style="color: #ffb718; font-weight: bold;">1.</span> REAL-TIME AVAILABILITY</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

You can see the issue in the screenshots here http://kinocreative.uk/img/

I have tried various combinations of spans, hrefs and text-transform to fix this to no avail.

Full email code here: https://pastebin.com/PfNmTeZc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook.com & Office 365 do not like dummy links. If you include them, you'll find small inconsistencies like what you're seeing to the background of an html based buttons background colour spreading to content below the button.

It's a simple (but annoying) issue with a simple fix. One technique I use is adding a fullstop after the #, like this:

```
<a href="#." ...></a>
```

Alternatively adding in a dummy url like http://www.example.com will work or even adding in your final urls at time of testing.

Comment: Worked a treat. I knew being an MS client it would be something utterly improbable. I'm used to their email "quirks", but hadn't come across that one before, thanks!